# VichUploaderBundle : image_name can't be null error

Tags: symfony, vichuploaderbundle

I'm using Symfony3.1 and I have just installed VichUploaderBundle.
I have followed the documentation but I get this error means that **Field 'image_name' can not be empty (null)**

**SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Le champ 'image_name' ne peut être vide (null)**

Config

```
vich_uploader:
db_driver: orm
mappings:
    product_image:
        uri_prefix:         /images/actualites
        upload_destination: kernel.root_dir/../web/images/actualites

        inject_on_load:     false
        delete_on_update:   true
        delete_on_remove:   true
```

the entity

```
/**
 *
 * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="actualite_image", fileNameProperty="imageName")
 *
 * @var File
 */
private $imageFile;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 *
 * @var string
 */
private $imageName;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 *
 * @var \DateTime
 */
private $updatedAt;

/**
 * @param File|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile $image
 *
 * @return Actualite
 */

public function setImageFile(File $image = null)
{
    $this->imageFile = $image;

    if ($image) {
        // It is required that at least one field changes if you are using doctrine
        // otherwise the event listeners won't be called and the file is lost
        $this->updatedAt = new \DateTime('now');
    }

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return File
 */
public function getImageFile()
{
    return $this->imageFile;
}

/**
 * @param string $imageName
 *
 * @return Actualite
 */
public function setImageName($imageName)
{
    $this->imageName = $imageName;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getImageName()
{
    return $this->imageName;
}
```

FormType:

```
->add('imageFile', FileType::class)
```

twig

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 //...
 {{ form_widget(form.imageFile) }}
```

Action

```
public function creerAction(Request $request)
{
    $entity = new Actualite();
    $form = $this->createForm(BaseType::class, $entity);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('backend_actualite_liste');
    }

    return $this->render('Backend/Actualite/creer.html.twig',array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: Where is the code that is producing this error. You show the Entity above, but we probably need to see the Controller code or form code where you do the upload. Can you edit your post and post that code please?

Comment: @AlvinBunk I have edited my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, actually according to what hous stated, this is the change required to the `app/config/config.yml` file:

```
vich_uploader:
    db_driver: orm
    mappings:
        actualite_image:
            uri_prefix:         /images/actualites
            upload_destination: kernel.root_dir/../web/images/actualites
```

Note to hous: You don't need those last 3 options in the config.yml file, since they are the default

Answer (score 1):

**Solved**

The error is that the upload mapping name in the config and the mapping name in the entity are different but they must be the same.

In the config file is **product_image** and in the entity is **actualite_image**.

Now I give them the same name and it works good now.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a note, there is different [Symfony3 setup here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/upload_file.html), which might be helpful.

I think for your setup, it's different for Symfony3.
Try this:

```
->add('imageFile', VichImageType::class, array(
    'required'      => false,
))
```

Also, you need this change too:

```
# app/config/config.yml
twig:
    form_themes:
        # other form themes
        - 'VichUploaderBundle:Form:fields.html.twig'
```

Comment: The error is that the upload mapping name in the config and the mapping name in the entity are different but they must be the same.

In the config file is product_image and in the entity is actualite_image.

Now I give them the same name and it works good now.